# kubectl port-forward: "pod does not exist" at the first time running?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, minikube

Follow [this](https://blog.hasura.io/sharing-a-local-registry-for-minikube-37c7240d0615) guide, I'm trying to start `minikube` and forward port at the boot time.

My script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -eux

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

minikube status || minikube start
minikube ssh 'grep docker.for.mac.localhost /etc/hosts || echo -e "127.0.0.1\tdocker.for.mac.localhost" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts'
minikube ssh 'test -f wait-for-it.sh || curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh'
minikube ssh 'chmod +x wait-for-it.sh && ./wait-for-it.sh 127.0.1.1:10250'
POD=$(kubectl get po --namespace kube-system | awk '/kube-registry-v0/ { print $1 }')
kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system $POD 5000:5000
```

Everything works fine except that `kubectl port-forward` said that pod does not exist at the first time running:

```sh
++ kubectl get po --namespace kube-system
++ awk '/kube-registry-v0/ { print $1 }'
+ POD=kube-registry-v0-qr2ml
+ kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system kube-registry-v0-qr2ml 5000:5000
error: error upgrading connection: unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist
```

If I re-run:

```sh
+ minikube status
minikube: Running
cluster: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100
+ minikube ssh 'grep docker.for.mac.localhost /etc/hosts || echo -e "127.0.0.1\tdocker.for.mac.localhost" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts'
127.0.0.1   docker.for.mac.localhost
+ minikube ssh 'test -f wait-for-it.sh || curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh'
+ minikube ssh 'chmod +x wait-for-it.sh && ./wait-for-it.sh 127.0.1.1:10250'
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for 127.0.1.1:10250
wait-for-it.sh: 127.0.1.1:10250 is available after 0 seconds
++ kubectl get po --namespace kube-system
++ awk '/kube-registry-v0/ { print $1 }'
+ POD=kube-registry-v0-qr2ml
+ kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system kube-registry-v0-qr2ml 5000:5000
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5000 -> 5000
Forwarding from [::1]:5000 -> 5000
```

I added a debug line before forwarding:

```sh
kubectl describe pod --namespace kube-system $POD
```

and saw this:

```sh
+ POD=kube-registry-v0-qr2ml
+ kubectl describe pod --namespace kube-system kube-registry-v0-qr2ml
Name:       kube-registry-v0-qr2ml
Namespace:  kube-system
Node:       minikube/192.168.99.100
Start Time: Thu, 28 Dec 2017 10:00:00 +0700
Labels:     k8s-app=kube-registry
        version=v0
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"kube-system","name":"kube-registry-v0","uid":"317ecc42-eb7b-11e7-a8ce-...
Status:     Running
IP:     172.17.0.6
Controllers:    ReplicationController/kube-registry-v0
Containers:
  registry:
    Container ID:   docker://6e8f3f33399605758354f3f546996067d834459781235d51eef3ffa9c6589947
    Image:      registry:2.5.1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://registry@sha256:946480a23b33480b8e7cdb89b82c1bd6accae91a8e66d017e21e8b56551f6209
    Port:       5000/TCP
    State:      Running
      Started:      Thu, 28 Dec 2017 13:22:44 +0700
```

Why `kubectl` said that it does not exist?

---

**Fri Dec 29 04:58:06 +07 2017**

Looking carefully at the events, I found something:

```
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubObjectPath                   Type            Reason                  Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------                   --------        ------                  -------
  20m           20m             1       kubelet, minikube                                       Normal          SuccessfulMountVolume   MountVolume.SetUp succ
eeded for volume "image-store"
  20m           20m             1       kubelet, minikube                                       Normal          SuccessfulMountVolume   MountVolume.SetUp succ
eeded for volume "default-token-fs7kr"
  20m           20m             1       kubelet, minikube                                       Normal          SandboxChanged          Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  20m           20m             1       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{registry}       Normal          Pulled                  Container image "registry:2.5.1" already present on machine
  20m           20m             1       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{registry}       Normal          Created                 Created container
  20m           20m             1       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{registry}       Normal          Started                 Started container
```

> Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.

Before:

```
Containers:
  registry:
    Container ID:       docker://47c510dce00c6c2c29c9fe69665e1241c457d0666174a7723062c534e7229c58
    Image:              registry:2.5.1
    Image ID:           docker-pullable://registry@sha256:946480a23b33480b8e7cdb89b82c1bd6accae91a8e66d017e21e8b56551f6209
    Port:               5000/TCP
    State:              Running
      Started:          Thu, 28 Dec 2017 13:47:02 +0700
    Last State:         Terminated
      Reason:           Error
      Exit Code:        2
      Started:          Thu, 28 Dec 2017 13:22:44 +0700
      Finished:         Thu, 28 Dec 2017 13:45:18 +0700
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      14
```

After:

```
Containers:
  registry:
    Container ID:       docker://3a7da784d3d596796111348757725f5af22b47c5edd0fc29a4ffbb84f3f08956
    Image:              registry:2.5.1
    Image ID:           docker-pullable://registry@sha256:946480a23b33480b8e7cdb89b82c1bd6accae91a8e66d017e21e8b56551f6209
    Port:               5000/TCP
    State:              Running
      Started:          Thu, 28 Dec 2017 19:03:04 +0700
    Last State:         Terminated
      Reason:           Error
      Exit Code:        2
      Started:          Thu, 28 Dec 2017 13:47:02 +0700
      Finished:         Thu, 28 Dec 2017 19:00:48 +0700
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      15
```

minikube logs:

> Dec 28 22:15:41 minikube localkube[3250]: W1228 22:15:41.102038
>   3250 docker_sandbox.go:343] failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker:
>   Couldn't find network status for kube-system/kube-registry-v0-qr2ml
>   through plugin: invalid network status for

Answer (score 6):

> POD=$(kubectl get po --namespace kube-system | awk '/kube-registry-v0/ { print $1 }')

Be aware that using a [selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) is almost certainly better than using text utilities, especially with "unstructured" output from `kubectl`. I don't know of any promises they make about the format of the default output, which is why `--output=json` and friends exist. However, in your case when you just want the name, there is a special `--output=name` which does what it says, with the mild caveat that the Resource prefix will be in front of the name (`pods/kube-registry-v0-qr2ml` in your case)

Separately, I see that you have "wait-for-it," but just because a port is accepting connections doesn't mean the Pod is **Ready**. You'll actually want to use `--output=json` (or more `awk` scripts, I guess) to ensure the Pod is both Running and Ready, with the latter status reached when kubernetes and the Pod agree that everything is cool.

I *suspect*, but would have to experiment to know for sure, that the error message is just misleading; it isn't truly that kubernetes doesn't know anything about your Pod, but merely that it couldn't port-forward to it in the state it's in.

You may also experience better success by creating a `Service` of `type: NodePort` and then talk to the Node's IP on the allocated port; that side-steps this kubectl-shell mess entirely, but does **not** side-step the Ready part -- only Pods in the Ready state will receive traffic from a Service

---

As a minor, pedantic note, `--namespace` is an argument to `kubectl`, and not to `port-forward`, so the most correct invocation is `kubectl --namespace=kube-system port-forward kube-registry-v0-qr2ml 5000:5000` to ensure the argument isn't mis-parsed

Comment: I had a very similar error (Pods do not exist), however it was the positioning of --namespace in my command which was the problem - as above, so thanks for that! :)